# Trying to write a code for a bill changer/coin vending kiosk

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a code for a bill changer where the amount of money inserted are converted back into coins for the user. The problem is I keep having decimals in my amount of 50c like 222.222 when i input 111.111. My 20c and 10c is unused.. Please help

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    double sum50c=0, sum20c=0, sum10c=0, remainder, remainder2, remainder3, end=0;
    double amount;

    do
    {

    printf("Please enter an amount(dollars):");
    scanf("%lf", &amount);

    amount=amount*100;

    if(amount<0){
        printf("Invalid Input\n");
        printf("Re-enter your amount:");
        scanf("%lf", &amount);
    }

    if(amount>=50){
        remainder=amount/50;
        sum50c=remainder;

    }else
    if(remainder!=0){
        remainder2=remainder/20;
        sum20c=remainder2;

    }else     
    if(remainder2!=0){
        remainder3=remainder3/10;
        sum10c=remainder3;

    }

    if(sum50c>200||sum20c>200||sum10c>200){
        end++;
    }else{
        end=0;
    }

    }
        while(end<=0);

    printf("The amount of 50cents=%lf, 20cents=%lf, 10cents=%lf", sum50c, sum20c, sum10c);


}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use real numbers. Use integers since coins are distributed discretely and there are no 5.55 cent coin. Work in cents (1 cent is atomic, and there cannot be anything smaller than that).

Comment: Also, `something / x` gives you the quotient, not the remainder. Change to integers as advised and then read up on the `%` (modulo) operator.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two errors in your code:

- Don't operate on floating-point numbers here. The number of coins will be a discrete number, which should be represented as `int` or maybe even `unsigned int`. The amount itself may be read in as floating-point number for simplicity, but it should also be converted to the number of cents as integerin order to avoid rounding errors.
- You have to find combinations of coins: 30c is 1%times;20c + 1×10c. That means that you can't use `else if` chains, which will only consider one type of coin. Treat all types of coin, highes denomination first, and then reduce the amount still to handle. Note that with 10c as smallest coin, you might not be able to give full change for all amounts.

Here's you example without the outer loop and without the strange `end` business:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num50c = 0,
        num20c = 0,
        num10c = 0;
    int amount;              // amount in cents
    double iamount;          // input amount in dollars

    printf("Please enter an amount: ");
    scanf("%lf", &iamount);

    amount = iamount * 100 + 0.5;

    if (amount < 0) {
        printf("Invalid Input\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    num50c = amount / 50;
    amount %= 50;

    num20c = amount / 20;
    amount %= 20;

    num10c = amount / 10;
    amount %= 10;

    printf("%d x 50c = %d\n", num50c, num50c * 50);
    printf("%d x 20c = %d\n", num20c, num20c * 20);
    printf("%d x 10c = %d\n", num10c, num10c * 10);
    printf("Remainder: %dc\n", amount);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To force `amount` to have integer values you should round the value after your division:

```
if(amount>=50)
{
        remainder=round(amount/50);
        sum50c=remainder;
}
```